# MS Word Page number in the same line as header

Tags: microsoft-word, headers

I am trying to add the page number that is in the same line as the existing header.
Not sure how to achieve this.

[image: Current output]

A friend of mine, who is using MAC version of Word, simply clicked add page number button to achieve this. (I am using windows 10).

[image: Friend's ouutput]

Can anyone tell me how to achieve my friend's output?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft article
[Add page numbers to a header or footer in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-page-numbers-to-a-header-or-footer-in-word-46d6dfe5-f99b-40d8-8809-be4808a291f4)
explains how to add the page number, to change where it appears and to modify its
appearance.

The procedure is:

- Click the header
- Go to the ribbon pane *Insert* and click *Page Numbering*
- Select *Current Position*
- Choose a style
- to change where the page number appears, select it
  and use repeatedly the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to switch its position between left, center, or right.